# How can I convert a JavaFX Table data to Apache POI Excel sheet on Button click event?

Tags: javafx, apache-poi

Below is my code snippet for generating a POI Excel report from the JavaFX Table data on button click action event. When I click on the button, it only gets column heading in the excel file generated. The data inside the column is not fetched.

I wish to fetch column heading as well as column data in the excel file to be generated.

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong ??

```
@FXML
private void btnReport(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("creation_from_fx");

        HSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
        HSSFCell cell;

        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("First name");
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("Last NAME");
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("Email");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("FXdatabase.xls"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");

        row = spreadsheet.createRow(2);
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(firstNameColumn.getCellData(index).toString());
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(lastNameColumn.getCellData(index).toString());
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue(emailColumn.getCellData(index).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the file before you write the data into the spreadsheet. Move the lines

```
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("FXdatabase.xls"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");
```

to the end of the `try` block. Also, you probably want to iterate over all items in the table - currently your code will only write one line (the one specified by `index`).

Comment: Oops ! so silly of me .. anyways thanks for the answer.. now I can try for all the rows..